# how to add svg to canvas, which is part of the object

Tags: canvas, svg

I am not able to add svg image to canvas, which is part of the object. If i add this svg image to canvas in `window.onload` function - it works, but if i do this inside
`handObj.prototype.svgToBlob`, the image is not displayed. If i copy and paste svg to the html it displays the image of keyboard. 
Does smth happens with scope?
How i could resolve this? I mean how to disply svg on canvas, from the function, which is part of object prototype?

//Svg is very large, this is a shortened version.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1300" height="600">
 <rect x="0" y="10" width="16" height="64" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
 <text x="16" y="31" font-family="Calibri" font-size="12" fill="white" id="r1b1" data-json="r1b1" data-modif="lowercase"  >&#110;</text>
 </svg>
```

//Log results

```
handObj.js:265 249 in timeout url=blob:http://localhost/bce88b61-edbe-4889-b131-6b2f36912560
handObj.js:266 250 img=[object HTMLImageElement]
handObj.js:267 <img src=​"blob:​http:​/​/​localhost/​bce88b61-edbe-4889-b131-6b2f36912560">​

The function which is part of object, and should disply svg on canvas. 

handObj.prototype.svgToBlob = function () {

    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

    this.genSvg();

    var kbsv = this.svgStr; //generates valid svg, i can display it , but not on canvas
    $("#tmp").html(kbsv); // displys svg

    // keyboard image 
    var img1 = new Image();
    var svg1 = new Blob( [kbsv], {type: 'image/svg+xml'} );
    console.log('246 this.svgStr='+this.svgStr);
    var url1 = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg1);
    console.log('247 url1='+url1); 

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    img1.onload = function() {
        console.log('217 this.ctx='+ctx); 
        console.log('249 in timeout url='+url1); 
        console.log('250 img='+img1); 
        console.log(img1);
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url1); 
    } // img1.onload = function() {
    img1.src = url1;

}  // handObj.prototype.svgToBlob = function () {
```

I also tried to add namespacesa according:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html

In this case svg is not dislayed al all, not only from the object, but also in the html page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body> 
        <svg:svg id='display' width='400' height='300'>
            <svg:circle id='cursor' cx='200' 
cy='150' r='7' fill='#0000ff' fill-opacity='0.5'/>
        </svg:svg> <br>
```

Comment: Please show the SVG source you want to draw on canvas. I think it has some troubles (no size, no namespace...)

Comment: most probably this twill solve all problems : https://github.com/canvg/canvg

Comment: I think loading SVG was succeed. >If i add this svg image to canvas in window.onload function - it works, but if i do this inside : If canvas was resized after drawing SVG, the graphic would be cleared. Please check existence of such codes as `canvas.width = 200` or `canvas.setAttribute("200")` before window.onload.

Comment: Thank you. I myself, finally, realised that i do not need canvas. It is enough svg as a part of object to achieve all amazing functionalities. Do not know why i put it on canvas. To achieve any movement on canvas is complicated issue related to paths, etc.. .  While the object has event property, thus svg becomes very interactive and flexible.